# Add link in Magento for custom module

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.5

I am creating a module for supplier in magento. I want to Supplier Login link at `top.links.`

How Can I add the link?

Also,can anybody tell me the the meaning of the tags like  `<customer_logged_out>` and `<customer_logged_in>` in `magento/app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml`

Beacause I used `<supplier_logged_in>` and `<supplier_logged_out>` in

`magento/app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/supplier.xml` its not working.

this is sample code from my file

```
<supplier_logged_in>
    <reference name="top.links">
        <action method="addLink" translate="label title" module="supplier"><label>Log 11Out</label><url helper="customer/getLogoutUrl"/><title>Log Out</title><prepare/><urlParams/><position>100</position></action>
    </reference>
</supplier_logged_in>
```

Also is there any reference for `<customer_logged_in>` file to make it working?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can add custom link inside your top links, more info can be found here http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/editing-magentos-top-links-the-better-way

```
<reference name="top.links">
                    <!-- Add custom links. Pretty self-explanatory.
                    Dig into app/code/core/Mage/Page/Block/Template/Links.php for more info -->
                    <action method="addLink" translate="label title">
                        <label>About Us</label>
                        <url>about</url>  <!-- can use full url also -->
                        <title>About Us</title>
                        <prepare>true</prepare> <!-- set true if adding base url param -->
                        <urlParams helper="core/url/getHomeUrl"/> <!-- base url - thanks @Russ! -->
                        <!-- there are a few param you can send to do different things in <urlParams> 
                                 dig into app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Url.php, around line 803 -->                   

                        <!-- below adds #add-fragment to the end of your url -->
                        <!-- <urlParams><_fragment>add-fragment</_fragment></urlParams> -->

                        <!-- below adds ?add-query to the end of your url -->
                        <!-- <urlParams><_query>add-fragment</_query></urlParams> -->

                        <!-- below gives you a new session id (i think...)-->
                        <!-- <urlParams><_nosid>true</_nosid></urlParams> -->

                        <!-- below replaces double quotes, single quotes, greater than, and less than signs 
                                 to their respective url escaped replacements (%22, %27, %3E, %3C) -->
                        <!-- <urlParams><_escape>i'm-a-blog-url</_escape></urlParams> -->

                        <position>1</position>
                        <liParams/>
                        <aParams>class="top-link-about-us"</aParams>
                        <beforeText></beforeText>
                        <afterText></afterText>
                    </action>
    </reference>
```

You need to add the code above in either `<default>` node or inside `<customer_logged_out>` or `<customer_logged_in>` (these two handles used by Magento to add functionality when customer is logged in or logged out in your store).

```
//app/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout/Update.php.
class Mage_Customer_Model_Observer
{
    public function beforeLoadLayout($observer)
    {
        $loggedIn = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn();

        $observer->getEvent()->getLayout()->getUpdate()
           ->addHandle('customer_logged_'.($loggedIn?'in':'out'));
    }
}
```

To use `<supplier_logged_in>` (if needed) inside your extension you need at first add custom layout handle inside your Magento custom extension. To start digging it I'd recommend the following articles:

http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/creating-custom-layout-handles/

http://www.classyllama.com/magento/add-custom-layout-handles-e-g-parent-categories